# How To Have A Delay When Changing UILabel Text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have got 3 empty UILabels on the screen and I am changing their text programmatically. I want to have a delay of 1.5 and 2 seconds... For example, first one pops up, 1 second delay, second one pops up, 1.5 second delay, third one pops up, 2 second delay.

I have written the lines of code to change the text already but they all pop up at the same time. `sleep();` doesn't work properly.

```
load1.text = @"Reading fingerprint...";

load2.text = @"Fingerprint read...";

load3.text = @"Determining result...";
```

That is the code I'm using to change the text. It happens when I press a button.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few approaches. One is to use `dispatch_after`:

```
// Show first now
load1.text = @"Reading fingerprint...";

// Show second after 1 second
int64_t delayInSeconds = 1.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    load2.text = @"Fingerprint read...";
});

// Show third after 2.5 seconds
delayInSeconds = 2.5;
popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    load3.text = @"Determining result...";
});
```

Of course it seems like it would be better to show the updated labels after each of those steps are actually completed instead of the artificial delays. Wouldn't it?

Comment: thank you very much! This worked. But now I want it to start the process over when they hit the button again. How would I go about this?

Comment: You simply call this same code again. Of course you probably need to reset the labels first.

Comment: Thank you very much @rmaddy ! This code works perfectly now I just need to set it to reset on the next button press. Thanks again!